# Push notification to alert for Enterprise update?

Tags: ios, push-notification, enterprise

Are there any suggestions for the feasibility/correctness of this solution? Enterprise app with quarterly updates. Client unwilling to use MDM solution.

Using push, alert the app of an update. An action on the notification or just opening the app pops a modal with a button to open Safari to download the updated app (url is in code). Modal has login info next to the button.

Safari opens, I copy and paste from the modal or just remember the login info. App installs. I reopen and the notif. is gone because a fresh install happened so no need to remove it.

Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand you right, you can explicitly open URL to manifest of your enterprise build right from your application code instead of opening html page with exactly the same url inside.

```
NSString * urlString =@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mywebsite.com/path_to_distr/manifest.plist"
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

This will launch the update process.

Comment: Thanks! This would work except my client wants to password protect everything. But thanks for the tip.